# Handling different resolutions within the same configuration group

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a normal-hdpi-480x800 layout, which includes buttons and similar graphics. I mostly use RelativeLayout, since it's recommended for better performance, and position my elements from the upper left bound relatively to each other.  According to screens_support.html this group might also include 600x1024 resolution devices. So, when I test the application on LG L9 (540x960), which also falls into normal-xhdpi, it looks horrible - it seems there's no difference between using pixels and dp. Here's an example of code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fb_post_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/share_fb_m_l"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/share_fb_m_t"
    android:background="@drawable/fb_btn" />
```

Any help ? What I might be doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify different dimensions in folders `values-ldpdi`, `values-mdpi`, `values-hdpi`, `values-xhdpi` if you need more control over button sizes according to screen density. Like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="share_fb_m_l">47dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="share_fb_m_t">57dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Update**: You can get more control over this:

Specify multiple different images for different screen resolutions and densities. To do so read supporting multiple screens. If you need even more precision in image scaling and quality you can use the fundamental size of screen attribute which is swdp - you can specify the smallest width of the screen where your image should be used. This is a qualifier name for a resource folder.

**Place your dimensions in these folders `values-sw540dp`, `values-sw540dp`, `values-sw600dp`** - these should serve as subfolders for more control.

Comment: `LG L9 (540x960), which also falls into normal-xhdpi` I meant that I've tested it on normal-hdpi-480x800 and LG L9 also falls into that group so I need dimen file for a subgroup :P

Comment: also consider including other folder qualifiers, you get get even better control over resources. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: but what is the meaning of dp units if I have to tweak like this ?

Comment: dp units make android automatically adjust the dimension according to screen density (not size) that's when it makes difference, if it is not enough for you, you need to obtain more control including screen size like this. dp units won't make a view much bigger when going form hdpi to xhdpi. That migh be the reason you don't see much difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22525/discussion-between-taras-and-midnight)